# How to open two or more files in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have many files and want to open these files with grouping.

```
inputfile1 = 'file1.csv'
inputfile2 = 'file2.csv'
inputfile3 = 'file3.csv'
inputfile4 = 'file4.csv'

LINE1 = open(inputfile1, inputfile2, mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read()
LINE2 = open(inputfile3, inputfile4, mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

But I have a error.

I tried to use (`and/or`) between input files in `open()`, but that did not help.

Question - how to open() two or more files?

Comment: You can only open one file at a time in one  `open()` call. It means that you should use `LINE1 = open(inputfile1, mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read()` etc. for each file separatelly

Comment: Perhaps you can show some actual file content and what you want the end result to look like?  At the moment, it's hard to understand what you're actually trying to do, which is probably why people are downvoting your question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
for number in range(10):
    with open("file%d.csv" %number, 'r') as f):
        reader = csv.reader(f, dialect = 'excel', delimiter = ';')
        for row in reader:
            print row
```

This will open file1.csv, file2.csv ...
The

```
%d
```

makes sure that you change the number in the file name
In the rest of the code, I read the data and print each row in your file.
Of course you can change it to whatever you wish to do with the data.

Of course, you can only handle one file at the time in your loop. However, you can use the loop to open and manipulate a lot of files in a consecutive fashion.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: many thanks, but I need to parse data from these files in another for cycle...
so I need to open files and use these lists in another for cycle.
for example:
a = [a, b, c, d]
for x in a:
 if x in LINE1 (LINE1 - with data from my files...)
print(x)

Comment: @Oleksii You could open each file, save the needed data from the opened file in a local dataframe/list (e.g. by using append() ), and use it later on in the script? Just a suggestion of course

Comment: I also prefer the "read all at once, process later" philosophy, as long as the file size allows it to load all of the data into memory. Makes it much easier to randomly access the data, which is possible but not convenient with a file handle.